# Finding the number of ways using multinomial theorem

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

My question is :

> If a team of $4$ persons is to be selected from $8$ males and $8$ females, then in how many ways can the selections be made to include at least one male?

Though I got the answer 
$$8C3 \times 8C1 + 8C2 \times 8C2 + 8C1 \times 8C3 + 8C4$$

But how can we solve this using multinomial theorem?

Comment: Well, if you ignore the restriction then there are $\binom {16}4$.  you then have to throw out the all female selections so subtract $\binom 84$.  Not sure if this is what you are looking for though.

Comment: Why do you think the multinomial theorem applies to this problem?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I'm just exploring different problems or cases which can be solved using the multinomial theorem. And thanks for edits.